# getter/setter Class from $variable w/out switch/if in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, switch-statement, getter-setter

I am using a table edit switch, which I want to integrate to Symfony.
This is the script I am talking about: [LINK](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/index.html)

Now this script sends requests that I am able to receive in symfony.

**Sender**

```
<a href="#" id="Username" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-url="/post/table1" data-title="Enter username">superuser</a>
```

**Receiver** (/post)

```
if($table == "table1"){
    $repo = "AppBundle:Table1";
}
...
/* Get correct repo/entry */
$repo = $em->getRepository($repo)->find($request->get('pk'));
```

That is somehow untested but should work I guess.

Now I want to update the according column, which is sent by `id="Username"`

What I'd like to achieve now is something like this: (I know this won't work)
`$repo->set.$request->get('id')('blabla')`

I could use a switch, but that needs to be quite large then.

Any other approach to this?

PS: I know it is not very safe to send values like this, but it's only for personal use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want call a setter from your request value, the following code will work :

```
$setter = 'set'.$request->request->get('id'); // is now equal to 'setUsername'
$repo->$setter('blabla'); // Assuming $repo is the entity retrieved by find();
```

Also, there is a clean way to do that is symfony called PropertyAccess, you just need the name of the property you want set/get .

Example :

```
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor;
// ...
$accessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();

// If the property 'username' is writable, set it
if ($accessor->isWritable($repo, 'username') {
    $accessor->setValue($repo, $request->request->get('id'), 'blabla');
}
```

See [Symfony PropertyAccess](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access/introduction.html#usage)

Comment: Looks nice, but the PropertyAccess version leads to this: `The property path constructor needs a string or an instance of \"Symfony\\Component\\PropertyAccess\\PropertyPath\". Got: \"NULL\"\" `

Comment: It's because your `$request->request->get('id')` is null. Replace it by the property name directly and it will works. Verify your request is working and contains your data. e.g. `$accessor->setValue($repo, 'username', 'blabla');`

Comment: EDIT: NVM the `$request`var was empty/wrong! Thank you!

Comment: Creating setter on the fly. Sometimes it can be so easy. Thx